# How to import Excel which is in HTML format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import

I have exported the data from database using HttpContext with formatting of table, tr and td. I want to read the same file and convert into datatable.

```
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='HTML Import;HDR={1};IMEX=1'" />

<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1'" />

    private DataTable GetTableFromExcel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            if (exclFileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(exclFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                string Extension = Path.GetExtension(exclFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                string FolderPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"]);
                //string NewFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", ""), FileName);
                string FilePath = Path.Combine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", FolderPath, FileName));
                exclFileUpload.SaveAs(FilePath);
                string conStr = "";
                switch (Extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }
                conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, true);
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                connExcel.Close();

                connExcel.Open();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                oda.Fill(dt);
                connExcel.Close();
                File.Delete(FilePath);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

When using the second connection string I am getting error "External table is not in the expected format on connection.Open()." But when using the first, I am getting error on reading the sheet name.

Please tell me how to read the sheet or, directly, data from Excel.

Comment: Hi! Did you have seen [this](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/master/readme.markdown)?

Comment: If you exported it into html format as you say (table with trs and tds) why are you treating it as excel?

Comment: @MladenOršolić:I am getting the Excel which is SAP created which exported as HTML to Excel.

Comment: Can you open it in notepad and update your question by adding sample of the data?

Answer (score 3):

I think This [Third party dll-(ExcellDataReader)](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) may help solve your problem.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
//...
//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
//...
//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
//...
//4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//5. Data Reader methods
while (excelReader.Read())
{
    //excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

//6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this online:
[C# Excel file OLEDB read HTML IMPORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238473/c-sharp-excel-file-oledb-read-html-import)

Here they say:

> Instead of using the sheetname, you must use the page title in the
>   select statement without the $. SELECT * FROM [HTMLPageTitle]

In that post they also link to this manual, which may come in handy, but is too long to copy here:
http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/12/reading_html_ta.html

If that doesn't work, I t think you will have to recreate the original excel so it remains an excel file, and not HTML (if that is at all possible in your scenario)

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing this issue due to different reasons. There are different solutions for this one of them is to make your solution debug as `x86`. Here is how you can change it to `x86`.

- Right click on sloution from Visual studio.
- Click configuration Manager
- Select `x86` from `Active solution platform` if available
- If not available click `New` and select or type `x86` and click ok.
- Rebuild solution and run you application.

If this deos not solve your problem you may have to install `32 bit` version of `office system drivers`. Here is a complete [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-MicrosoftACEOLEDB120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine.aspx) explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a deep research I found the solution.

First convert the particular Excel file to an html page by using the following code.

```
File.Move(Server.MapPath("~/Foldername/ExcelName.xls",Path.ChangeExtension(Server.MapPath("~/Foldername/ExcelName.xls"), ".html"));
```

we have to download HTML string and extract  content.  tag contains  and  tags but it may have style properties. So first we have to avoid these style properties and after we can get required content from table.

```
string url = Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/Excelname.html");
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string fileContent = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Here we have to format HTML tags for avoid style properties.

```
const string msgFormat = "table[{0}], tr[{1}], td[{2}], a: {3}, b: {4}";   
const string table_pattern = "<table.*?>(.*?)</table>"; 
const string tr_pattern = "<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>"; 
const string td_pattern = "<td.*?>(.*?)</td>"; 
const string a_pattern = "<a href=\"(.*?)\"></a>"; 
const string b_pattern = "<b>(.*?)</b>";
```

After through looping we can find `<tr>` and `<td>` elements. Then we can get content within `<td></td>` tags by using this method.

```
private static List<string> GetContents(string input, string pattern)
{ 
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline); 
    List<string> contents = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (Match match in matches) 
    contents.Add(match.Value); 
    return contents; 
}
```

Then we can insert imported records to database by each row.

[Reference link here](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/import-records-from-html-table-and-store-to-database-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1053.aspx)